# Graphviz API: ND_width and ND_height macros does not work, while agsafeset with "width" and "height" attributes - does. What's wrong?

Tags: graphviz

I'm working with Graphviz API, Visual C++. Before I call **gvLayout** to calculate node coordinates, I have to set node width and height (for each node in the graph). The problem is, **ND_width** and **ND_height** macro approach, just does not seem to have affect, while setting same values with **agsafeset** works as expected. I just don't want to use string-based APIs like **agsafeset**, because I'm processing bunch of nodes in a loop, and prefer to set width and height values with **ND_width(pNode)** and **ND_height(pNode)** (or directly as **pNode->u.width** and **pNode->u.height**). What am I doing wrong?

Following code does not work (does not have any effect):

```
const DWORD dwPixelsPerInch = 96;

ND_width(pGvzNode) = (double)dwWidthInPixels / dwPixelsPerInch;
ND_height(pGvzNode) = (double)dwHeightInPixels / dwPixelsPerInch;
```

While following code works:

```
CStringA csaValue;

csaValue.Format("%f", (double)dwWidthInPixels / dwPixelsPerInch);
agsafeset(pGvzNode, "width", csaValue.GetBuffer(), "");

csaValue.Format("%f", (double)dwHeightInPixels / dwPixelsPerInch);
agsafeset(pGvzNode, "height", csaValue.GetBuffer(), "");
```

P.S.: I use Graphviz solely for layout, I do custom rendering, so all I need is calculation of nodes' and edges' coordinates (in pixels) given nodes' width and height (in pixels). I'm setting these values just before calling gvLayout (for "dot"). I'm setting **agsafeset(pGvzNode, "fixedsize", "1", "")** as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

agsafeset sets the node attributes, which are used by gvLayout to calculate the layout information, while ND_width and ND_height are used to get the layout size. Before gvLayout is called, the ND_width and ND_height can set the values, but the values you have set will be overwritten by gvLayout. So you must use agsafeset, the ND_width and ND_height cannot work.